# Using constants as keys while creating Dictionary in Type script

Tags: typescript, jsonparser

I've a "constants.ts" file which has below code:

```
export const PLACEMENT_ID = 'placementId';
export const TIMESTAMP = 'timeStamp';
```

In my type script code, I'm trying to use the constants as keys while creating a dictionary and then convert it to JSON to write it to a file.

```
import * as c from './constants';

let obj = JSON.stringify({ c.PLACEMENT_ID: "bob", c.TIMESTAMP: 34 });
console.log(obj);
let parsedData = JSON.parse(obj);

console.log(parsedData[c.PLACEMENT_ID]);
console.log(parsedData[c.TIMESTAMP]);
```

Its throwing error:

```
An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
```

I couldn't find any particular reason why is it throwing that error.

Comment: @GarethMa, My result is same... I want to place the keys in the constants file so that I can use them in multiple files. I can't hard code them as "{ 'placementId': "bob", 'timeStamp': 34 }"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine:

```
let obj = JSON.stringify({ [c.PLACEMENT_ID]: "bob", [c.TIMESTAMP]: 34 });
```